# Regex not matching unicode when removing emoji's from email body

Tags: php, regex, unicode

**Update**

After playing with: regex101, I found that it only ever matches on 1 result and when changing the modifier to \g, it freaks out! :( - Sample test: https://regex101.com/r/yD9hI4/1

**Update 2**

When adding a `ug` modifier to that sample above, it (kinda) works! But PHP throws an exception with `Unknown modifier g` :( Can't win! Hate regex...

**Update 3**

Have since read up on `preg_replace` and it doesn't understand `\g` because it defaults to match all when a limit is omitted (which it is). So now I really don't understand why `preg_replace` only finds one match and ignores the rest.

**Original Question**
I'm trying to remove all references of emoji's / Unicode picture characters, but my regex isn't matching against gmail. I've got the following email that I've downloaded to process:

```
Test

*Test*


*[image: Inline images 1]*

*Test?*

Test?

=F0=9F=98=88

TEST!
```

The `=F0=9F=98=88` is what I'm trying to get rid of. In this instance it is the smiley with horns (google flavour). Which is represented by unicode value: `U+1F608` (hex/utf-8: `f0 9f 98 88`) - Now, this is the only bugger that won't go away, everything else is covered by my regex of:

`/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u` (smilies) and `/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u` (transport etc)

Now before anyone points out the obvious and says: "=F0=9f=98=88 isn't what you're searching for", I agree, but I'd like to know why, when I test with other emoji's, only the wee devil bloke survives my parsing?

Can anyone (with far greater regex knowledge than I) explain what is going wrong please?

**Requested Code**

```
private function removePictureCharacters($text) {
    $clean_text = "";
    // Match Emoticons
    $regexEmoticons = '/([\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}])/u';
    $clean_text = preg_replace($regexEmoticons, '', $text);
    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
    $regexSymbols = '/([\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}])/u';
    $clean_text = preg_replace($regexSymbols, '', $clean_text);
    // Match Transport And Map Symbols
    $regexTransport = '/([\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}])/u';
    $clean_text = preg_replace($regexTransport, '', $clean_text);
    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols
    $regexMisc = '/([\x{2600}-\x{26FF}])/u';
    $clean_text = preg_replace($regexMisc, '', $clean_text);
    // Match Dingbats
    $regexDingbats = '/([\x{2700}-\x{27BF}])/u';
    $clean_text = preg_replace($regexDingbats, '', $clean_text);

    return $clean_text;
}
```

Comment: `/g` is unknown because `preg_replace` replaces all occurrences by default, so the `/g` is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Have just seen that reading php docs. However, preg_replace isn't finding all results. It matches and removes one and leaves the others. Yet on regex101, I can get the exact outcome I'm aiming for. I should also point out that I've not set a limit for preg_replace either, so it should default to all.

Comment: Show how you are calling `preg_replace`

Comment: Probably unrelated, but there is no reason to wrap the expressions in parentheses.

Comment: Aye. That was me clutching at straws while debugging. Made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I have a hack that is pretty fragile, but it does get the job done:

```
private function removePictureCharacters($text) {
    $clean_text = "";

    // Never trust a horned smiler
    $smiley = json_decode('"\u1F608"');
    $clean_text = preg_replace("/$smiley/u", '', $text);

    // Match Emoticons
    $regexEmoticons = '/([\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}])/u';
    ...
}
```